# SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted - Which password is affected?

Tags: authentication, passwords, root

Logwatch shows that proftpd was tried to be logged into using root

```
0.0.0.0 (111.254.68.221[111.254.68.221]) - SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted
```

I found:

```
Normally, proftpd does not allow root logins under any circumstance. If a client attempts to login as root, using the correct password, a special security message is logged:

  SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted
```

It says `login as root, using the correct password`. How do I find out which password the hacker knows?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Reading your question it seems like it answers itself: the hacker knows the root password.